# Create Trigger to call Stored Procedure if Condition is met

Tags: stored-procedures, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

SQL Server 2008 R2

I have a stored procedure which does not have any parameters, it simply updates a table based on static criteria.

I would like to call this stored procedure if an insert is done on my dbo.item table, but only if the data inserted to the dbo.item.item column begins with 'F-'

If the insert on dbo.item.item does not begin with 'F-' I do not want to call the Stored Procedure.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: So what's your question? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Word of warning: the trigger will be called **once per statement** - so if you have an `INSERT` that inserts 20 rows from e.g. a `SELECT`, you get the trigger called once - with 20 rows in the `Inserted` pseudo table. Also: the triggers should be really lean, mean and fast - **do NOT do extensive processing** in the context of a trigger! That'll kill your system performance. So **AVOID** cursors by all means in a trigger!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerName FOR YOURTABLE
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
--Here you need to get the columns list which are starts with F, from sys.columns and concate these then assign to variable. Next pass the variable 
--IF UPDATE (your Diclared variable name)
IF UPDATE (FColumnName,FColumnName1,FColumnName2,....)
BEGIN
EXEC Procedure 
END
END
```

Comment: I was able to get the results I desired by using your suggestion Vagalla. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the trigger I used.  Do you see any performance issues arising from how it is written?

```
create trigger FixtureJob
on job
for insert
as
Begin
Declare @item varchar(30)
Select @item =(select LEFT(item,2) from inserted)
if @item = 'f-'
begin
execute ami_reports..FixtureJobDataUpdate
end 
end
```